# Temperature probe calibration

Tags: sensor, calibration

How would you design a replaceable temperature sensor probe such that end users do not have to send the entire unit (processor plus probe) away to be re-calibrated? So that you could just send them a new calibrated probe that they could plug in and it would "just work" without having to program in new calibration parameters (e.g. offsets, polynomial coefficients, or what have you)?

Comment: Have the a ROM onboard the probe. The problem is...what's going to calibrate the electronics reading the probe? The probe isn't the only thing that can go out of calibration. But maybe you don't care about that.

Comment: include the analog section with the sensor ... have only digital signals at the interface

Comment: You are right @jsotola I'll withdraw the question

Comment: Using an interchangeable sensor is the most popular way in industry. Eg. RTD, thermocouple, thermistor.

Comment: The first and most important thing is what are the tolerances at what temperature(s)? That has a big impact on the answers to your question.  A tolerance of +-0.0001 degree is much different then one that is +- 1.0 degree.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany could you possibly elaborate on your comment as an answer? How does  an interchangeable sensor not need system level calibration parameters changed when the probe is swapped out

Comment: @Gil 0.1C is the accuracy I'm considering

Comment: @vicatcu  I've seen [a handful independent times] this problem solved with a handful of very different approaches.  Each approach was dictated by the details of the application.  The question is completely silent about the application.  On that note, -1.

Comment: @nickalexeev it's laboratory refrigeration and freezer monitoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interchangeable probes are the most common way in industry to do this. Only if the sensor is very unusual in some way and it's impractical to make them interchangeable would one want to accept individually calibrated sensors. Sometimes a simple zero shift (single point) user calibration is provided which allows a small correction at a single temperature.

For example, a Class AA RTD has an interchangeability of 0.1°C + T*0.0017 where T is the temperature in °C. So at 40°C the sensor error will contribute less than +/-0.17°C.  That's more than good enough for most purposes. The sensors are manufactured to be that accurate (via laser trimming and control of the metal and substrate). Thermocouples have more like 1° + 0.4% using special limits of error wire (though the error at the cold junction temperature will be zero, from thermodynamics). Those errors refer to the *matching* of the actual sensor to the (nonlinear) curves for that sensor type.

On the other hand, some sensors for extreme accuracy and extreme temperatures are supplied with individual polynomial coefficients matching serial numbers and those values have to be loaded into the measurement system. That's very, very expensive (especially the testing of the sensors) and potentially error prone so it's best avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The most foolproof way is to build the ADC into the probe, along with a microcontroller that contains the calibration.

The probe transmits the data digitally to the processor *after* applying the calibration.